# Combine a variable @variable with a SELECT statement and INSERT to a new table SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, select

I'm trying to combine and insert a variable called @FormInstanceID with an output of a query.  so INSERT #tmp1 (@FormInstanceID, #tmp.*) I've tried several different methods but I still get errors. The last attempt; I decided to list all the fields (long and boring method I know) and then list all the values. 
Still the system complains, this time it says, tha: " Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS". Additionally it complains that the number of fields in the INSERT statement is not equal the number of Values provided, which is not true. The bottom line question is; how do I combine the variable @FormInstanceID with and output of a query and insert it in the new table.

```
enter code here 
USE MyForms;
DECLARE @FormInstanceID INT
DECLARE @licznik INT
DECLARE @numberOfInstances INT
SET @licznik = 0

SELECT FormInstanceId
INTO #allInstances
FROM MyForms.dbo.FormInstance
WHERE FormDefinitionId = 263
AND CreatedDate BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2017-02-01 00:00:00.000'

SET @numberOfInstances = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #allInstances)

CREATE TABLE #tmp
(Questions VARCHAR(255) ,
QNum VARCHAR(255) ,
QStatusInt VARCHAR(255) ,
QuestionCount VARCHAR(255) ,
WeightedScores VARCHAR(255) ,
Observation VARCHAR(255) ,
Aspect VARCHAR(255) ,
AspectSort VARCHAR(255) ,
QStatus VARCHAR(255) ,
QComments VARCHAR(255) ,
WorkOrderNumber VARCHAR(255))

CREATE TABLE #tmp1
(FormInstanceID VARCHAR(255),
Questions VARCHAR(255) ,
QNum VARCHAR(255) ,
QStatusInt VARCHAR(255) ,
QuestionCount VARCHAR(255) ,
WeightedScores VARCHAR(255) ,
Observation VARCHAR(255) ,
Aspect VARCHAR(255) ,
AspectSort VARCHAR(255) ,
QStatus VARCHAR(255) ,
QComments VARCHAR(255) ,
WorkOrderNumber VARCHAR(255))

WHILE ( @licznik ) <= (@numberOfInstances)

BEGIN

SET @FormInstanceID =  (SELECT TOP 1 #allInstances.FormInstanceId from #allInstances)

--PRINT '@licznik: ' + CAST(@licznik AS VARCHAR(255))
--PRINT 'FormInstanceID: ' + CAST(@FormInstanceID AS VARCHAR(255))
--PRINT 'NumberOfInstances: ' + CAST(@numberOfInstances as VARCHAR(255))
set @licznik = @licznik + 1

INSERT #tmp EXEC [MyForms].[dbo].[ReportsGetSecurityInspectionFormHeaderDetails] @FormInstanceID
INSERT #tmp1 (FormInstanceID,Questions,QNum,QStatusInt,QuestionCount,WeightedScores,Observation,Aspect,AspectSort,QStatus,QComments,WorkOrderNumber)
VALUES (CAST(@FormInstanceID AS VARCHAR(255)),#tmp.Questions,#tmp.QNum,#tmp.QStatusInt,#tmp.QuestionCount,#tmp.WeightedScores,#tmp.Observation,#tmp.Aspect,#tmp.AspectSort,#tmp.QStatus,#tmp.QComments,#tmp.WorkOrderNumber);


DELETE FROM #allInstances WHERE #allInstances.FormInstanceId = @FormInstanceID

END

select * from #tmp1

DROP TABLE #tmp
DROP TABLE #tmp1
DROP TABLE #allInstances
```

> (84 row(s) affected)
>   Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 65
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
>   Msg 109, Level 15, State 1, Line 65
>   There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

`#tmp` is a table just like `MyForms.dbo.FormInstance`. Just like you wouldn't use `MyForms.dbo.FormInstance.columnName` as a variable inside a `insert into...values()` clause, you can't do it with the temp table either. Select from the temp table just as you would from a regular table:

Replace:

```
INSERT #tmp1 (FormInstanceID,Questions,QNum,QStatusInt,QuestionCount,WeightedScores,Observation,Aspect,AspectSort,QStatus,QComments,WorkOrderNumber)
VALUES (CAST(@FormInstanceID AS VARCHAR(255)),#tmp.Questions,#tmp.QNum,#tmp.QStatusInt,#tmp.QuestionCount,#tmp.WeightedScores,#tmp.Observation,#tmp.Aspect,#tmp.AspectSort,#tmp.QStatus,#tmp.QComments,#tmp.WorkOrderNumber);
```

with:

```
INSERT #tmp1 (FormInstanceID,Questions,QNum,QStatusInt,QuestionCount,WeightedScores,Observation,Aspect,AspectSort,QStatus,QComments,WorkOrderNumber)
select CAST(@FormInstanceID AS VARCHAR(255)),tmp.Questions,tmp.QNum,tmp.QStatusInt,tmp.QuestionCount,tmp.WeightedScores,tmp.Observation,tmp.Aspect,tmp.AspectSort,tmp.QStatus,tmp.QComments,tmp.WorkOrderNumber
from #tmp as tmp;

delete from #tmp;
```